# space programs/projects/competitions/courses ..etc?

Tags: amateur-observing

My name is Meryem (or Meer), I'm 15 years old and I've been fond of space and astronomy since two years.

I read books about astronomy, love to search and write reviews about astronomy topics and sometimes I share them with some people.

I really want to make achievements and do activities related to astronomy, but I can't because my country's environment here doesn't support those space activities, so I came here to ask if you know such as space course or a space program which gives students around the world an opportunity to take part in it, or something like that..
or even if you know the right people to ask them about these stuff, tell me.
Thanks.

Comment: There are plenty of online international communities for astronomy amateurs. I would start there

Comment: I know, but I need to recognize them, that's why I asked. u can tell me about their names/people/communities/locations/websites,etc.

Answer (score 2):

Astronomy is a broad field, and so the possible activities and interests can vary A LOT.

My recommendation is to try three things: look for local observatories and astronomy clubs,or your national one. Maybe also your math or physics teacher can help. There are somewhat regularly events and things hosted by esa and nasa etc. Check their outreach sites.

Search the Web. There is a plethora of dedicated online communities with astronomical topics.

There do exist youth camps dedicated to astronomy. Noteworthy is the [IAYC](https://iayc.org/), the international astronomical youth camp. It is a 3-week long camp which takes place each summer somewhere in Europe. I can highly recommend that. Similar might exist in other parts of the world and does exist on some national levels

Comment: I've just seen the IAYC and it REALLY AMAZED  ME!, i've read the whole of wax about it and i'm waiting for the 2023 camp enthusiastically.Thank you alot.